# How to get value from <h3> tag in Selenium WebDriver, Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have html code:

```
<div class="description">
<h3><strong>Samsung</strong> Galaxy SII (I9100)</h3>
<div class="phone_color"> ... </div>
...
</div>
```

I want to get the value *Samsung Galaxy SII (I9100)* from /h3> tag using Selenium 2 (WebDriver)

Any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is written in C#, but it shouldn't be difficult to convert it over to Java:

```
/** Declare variables **/
string descriptionTextXPath = "//div[contains(@class, 'description')]/h3";

/** Find the element **/
IWebElement h3Element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(descriptionTextXPath));

/** Grab the text **/
string descriptionText = h3Element.Text;
```

Depending on whether you have other div elements with the 'description' class, you may need to further fine tune your results.

---

Just in case:

In order to find all divs on the page that act as descriptions for further use, you can do this:

```
/** Declare XPath variable **/
string descriptionElementXPath = "//div[contains(@class, 'description')]";

/** Grab all description div elements **/
List<IWebElement> descriptionElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(descriptionElementXPath ));
```

You can then use a forloop to go through each element and grab the data you need.

The following is the conversion of above C# code to Java:

/** Declare variables **/

```
String descriptionTextXPath = "//div[contains(@class, 'description')]/h3";
```

/** Find the element **/

```
IWebElement h3Element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(descriptionTextXPath));
```

/** Grab the text **/

```
String descriptionText = h3Element.toString();
```

OR,

```
String descriptionText = h3Element.getText();
```

Comment: You can use the following xpath also:
//div[@class='description']/h3
Or, If you want to use cssSelector, you can use as below:
div.description > h3

Comment: How to get that element using CSS selector instead of XPath?

Answer (score 2):

```
WebElement divElement = driver.findelement(By.classname("description"));
String str = divElement.getText();
System.out.println(str);
```

This is perfect..
It helped..
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement divElement = driver.findelement(By.classname("description"));
String str = divElement.getText();
enter code here
```

str contains the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("h3"));
```