# i m trying to find element href by selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium, find, href, element

Native code for what i want to make automation.This is the a href tag

```
<a href="http://www.itpathsolutions.cu.ma/juniorApp/admin/user">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>User Management</span>
                <small class="label pull-right bg-red">10</small>
              </a> here
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value from <h3> tag in Selenium WebDriver, Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902953/how-to-get-value-from-h3-tag-in-selenium-webdriver-java)

Comment: Need to add more html where contains <a href...>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPATH

```
//a[contains(@href, 'itpathsolutions')]
```

OR

```
//span[text()='User Management']/../a
```

Comment: Its not working.I have already tried it,   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://www.itpathsolutions.cu.ma/juniorApp/admin/user'")).click();

Comment: Both is not working? Edited the 2nd one. It should work.

Comment: Wrong syntax. Should be driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'itpathsolutions.cu.ma/juniorApp/admin/user')]")).click()

Comment: I have tried the first one. But it didnt work.
I dont understand second one.How to use  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='User Management']/../a")).click(); like this?

Comment: 1st one, you used wrong syntax, please take a look at my 3rd comment; 2nd one: yes

Answer (score 0):

if you want to click on give link then try following code.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.LinkText("User Management 10"))).Click();
```

if any issue then let me know.